# Error undefined using MySQL table data to populate nivoSlider variables

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write code which uses nivoSlider to display dynamic images stored on the server. I need to use the data returned by a query to populate the variable in the nivoSlider script.

The issue I have is how can I pass the returned data so that each displayed image uses the correct data for "Effect","TimeLapse",
"AnimSpeed", "Slices", "BoxCols" and "BoxCols". The code below produces a blank image as each loop runs. The console displays an "undefined" which points to the path of an image with undefined on the end,  example.com/apps/signage/1/DS2/undefined

I have tried many ways to do this but none of them work. Where am I going wrong?

Below is the code construction

```
<?php
while($row_Signage = mysql_fetch_array($Signage)){ 
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
console.log("MORE THAN ZERO )");
var TimeLapse = '<?php echo $row_Setting['TimeLapse'];?>';
var Effect = '<?php echo $row_Setting['Effect'];?>';
console.log("EFFECT", Effect);
var AnimSpeed = '<?php echo $row_Setting['AnimSpeed'];?>';
var Slices = '<?php echo $row_Setting['Slices'];?>';
var BoxCols = '<?php echo $row_Setting['Cols'];?>';
var BoxRows = '<?php echo $row_Setting['Rows'];?>';


$('#slider').nivoSlider({
effect: Effect,
slices: Slices,
boxCols:BoxCols,
boxRows: BoxRows,
animSpeed: AnimSpeed,
pauseTime: TimeLapse,
startSlide: 0,
directionNav: false,
controlNav: false,
controlNavThumbs: false,
pauseOnHover: false,
manualAdvance: false,
randomStart: false,
beforeChange: function(){},
afterChange: function(){},
slideshowEnd: function(){},
lastSlide: function(){},
afterLoad: function(){}
});
});
</script>

<?php
echo '<img src="/'.$ImagePath .''.$row_Signage['PromotionImage'].'" /> ';
} 
?>
```

Comment: have you tried to inspect the code in your page as displayed in the browser? you probably will realize you have to move some part of the code out of the php loop

Comment: I suggest you debug `$row_Signage`, check to see if there is data at all and it may be only a typo for the column name.

Comment: @ skobaljic hi, I have checked and double checked the code for typos and there is none. The $row_Signage returns 2 records which is what I am expecting. I have also moved code from inside the loop in so many different ways I am now totally lost as to how to get this to work. If I said I have been working on this all weekend that would be an underestimation of the amount of time. I am now totally stuck.I am working on the assumption the  nivoSlider can accept different variables for each side effect.

Comment: Lelio Faieta Hi and thanks for your reply. Have tried many ways of writing the script but none of them work.

Comment: Does anyone know of any examples of  nivoSlider working with dynamic data for the  nivoSlider variables